# Talend Training/Tutorials

Tags: talend

Can anyone recommend a good source of material for learning how to use Talend Open Studio For Data Integration?

I've had a look at the TalendForge tutorials but was wondering if a more cohesive training resource exists for beginners?

I've search the Interweb and can't find anything that isn't off TalendForge or a book with terrible reviews!

Any suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some reference manuals which can be downloaded from [official website](http://www.talend.com/download.php). Once you go to this link, goto tab `Data Integration` there, at the bottom of the page you can find   a section `User Documentation`. Download the appropriate pdfs.

We get minimal help from them, but self exploration would give better results once we have been through these materials.

Comment: thanks, Rp-. Looks like there's really nothing out there from the wider community (i.e. not Talend Forge). I'll chase them up on some direct training, at least after a bit more familiarisation on my own.